# What is the average angle planes wings they need to fly?

Tags: airliner, angle-of-attack

The planes I am talking about are everyday passenger plane's, not fighters. Do you know what the angle needs to be for it to create enough lift so the plane can fly?

Comment: Do you mean [Angle of Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack)?

Comment: I do. Thank you

Comment: That helped a lot. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle of attack airplanes fly at while cruising is called the optimum angle of attack (around 4 degrees) which meets the max.(L/D).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: @TrentAlexanderArnold you're most welcome.